# Turn a javascript to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a task where the customer enters their contact information, and then all the details will appear on an alert box, I am facing a problem with converting a javascript code to JSON

```
<script type="text/language">

var 
 function getinfo() {
try{ var  firstName =
    document.myForm.firstName.value;

 var LastName =
    document.myForm.LastName.value;

 FullName= firstName + LastName;


    var Gender =
    document.myForm.Gender.value;


var mail =
    document.myForm.mail.value;


var Telephone =
    document.myForm.Telephone.value;


        var MobilePhone =
     document.myForm.MobilePhone.value;

alert("FullName :  "+FullName  +"<br/> Mail: " + mail  +      "<br/>Telephone:" + Telphone  +"<br/>Mobile: " + MobilePhone);
}catch(err){alert('Exception :: '+err)}

  }
  </script>
```

Comment: I dont see where you are converting it to json?

Comment: Side note: it would be significantly easier to open the browser's Javascript console and look at the error messages there instead of wrapping the code in a try..catch block and alerting the error.

Comment: @AleksandarĐokić YAP, can I get help on how to convery it to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your script has some errors:

1. it's `document.forms.myForm` and so on.
2. you didn't define "`FullName`" as a variable.
3. you use "`Telphone`" in the alertbox instead of "`Telephone`"

I've corrected them here:

```
<script type="text/language">
document.forms.myForm.elements.sub.onclick= function()
{
try{ var  firstName = document.forms.myForm.firstName.value;

    var LastName = document.forms.myForm.lastName.value;

    var FullName= firstName + LastName;

    var Gender =document.forms.myForm.Gender.value;

    var mail = document.forms.myForm.mail.value;

    var Telephone = document.forms.myForm.Telephone.value;

    var MobilePhone =document.forms.myForm.MobilePhone.value;

    alert("FullName :  "+FullName  +"<br/> Mail: " + mail  +      "<br/>Telephone:" + Telephone  +"<br/>Mobile: " + MobilePhone);
    }catch(err){alert('Exception :: '+err)}
}
</script>
```

But your script hasn't got to do anything with converting something to JSON.
You might use `JSON.stringify()` to "JSONify" your variables.